# Octave with Casadi under Linux fails to load liboctinterp.so

Tags: linux, installation, octave

I am getting the following error when I want to load an sx variable:

```
failed to load: liboctinterp.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have:
GNU Octave Version: 4.2.2
Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-96-generic
The error is thrown after adding the CasADi to the path and defining/loading an sx/mx variable.

Comment: I can confirm that I downloaded, installed, and used casadi as per the website's instructions, and it works. So your problem is likely to do with your octave installation. How did you install octave?

Comment: I had an old installation of octave and just updated it as you do:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install octave

Comment: It does not seem to me that the packaged version contains this file. (e.g. `apt-file search liboctinterp.so.7` does not return any results). The source-compiled version does. I would generally recommend installing octave from source; it's not as painful as it sounds :)